# Change sound button image on clicking another button swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am creating a Tableview inside which is Tableviewcell and on cell there is a label and sound button. For each label there is a sound on button click. When I click for the first time on btn1 the sound plays and the button image changes to "pause" when I click again the same button sound stops and the image changes to "play" works perfectly in this manner but when I click for the first time on one button let suppose btn1 and without clicking it again (stoping sound) I click on btn2, the sound of the btn1 stops and the image of btn1 nor  btn2 changes. I want that when I click on btn 2,3, or 4 the previous sound should stop, the  image of previous button (means all buttons except the current) should change to "play" and the current clicked button should change to "pause"  and the sound of the previous click should stop and the current  clicked should play.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sound: UIButton!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate , GADInterstitialDelegate {

    var countsNumberOfButtonClicks = 0
    var countsNumberOfInfoBtnClicks = 0
    var isFirstTime = false
    var player : AVAudioPlayer! = nil
    var titleAlert: String!

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    var toggleState = 1


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.

    {

    let myCell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        myCell.titleLable.text = self.Duck[indexPath.row]

        myCell.sound.tag = indexPath.row
        myCell.sound.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.playSound), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
     return myCell
    }

   @IBAction func playSound(sender: UIButton) {

            if toggleState == 1 {
            let fullName: String = self.Duck[sender.tag]
            let fullNameArr = fullName.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fullNameArr[0], ofType:"wav", inDirectory: "sounds")
            let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
            do {
                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
                player.prepareToPlay()
            } catch {
                print("Problem in getting File")
              }   
            player.play()
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            print("toggle state 1")
            toggleState = 2
        }
        else {
            player.pause()
            toggleState = 1
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            print("Toggle state else")
 }
```

[Simulator result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Did2e.png)

Comment: Most people have long forgotten Swift 2.

Comment: i was using this in 2016 for 3 years i stopped development now a few days ago i started again thats why swift2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you class, declare a variable,

`var currentlyPlaying : UIButton?`

And wherever you play the sound, store the button which played the sound in this variable and whenever this variable is about to be change, reset the previous ones image and store the new one.

```
@IBAction func playSound(sender: UIButton) {

        if currentlyPlaying != sender || toggleState == 1 {

        //Set image in previous
        currentlyPlaying?.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png")

        if player != nil{
            player.pause()
        }

        let fullName: String = self.Duck[sender.tag]
        let fullNameArr = fullName.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fullNameArr[0], ofType:"wav", inDirectory: "sounds")
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
            player.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print("Problem in getting File")
          }   
        player.play()


        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        //Store new
        currentlyPlaying = sender

        print("toggle state 1")

        if sender != currentlyPlaying{
            toggleState = 2
        }

        myTableView.reloadData()

    }
    else {
        player.pause()
        toggleState = 1
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        print("Toggle state else")
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193942/discussion-on-answer-by-mihir-change-sound-button-image-on-clicking-another-butt).

Comment: clicking on the same button again doesn't stops the sound nor changes the image to pause. i tried the edited code